# Controlling the position of an element only with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a button that, when pressed, shows a `div`. The `div` adapts its width and height to the content, so neither the width nor the height are known.

The `div` has a `position: absolute;` style because it needs to act exactly like a dropdown (meaning, it must overlap/stay on top of the content of the DOM).

Is there a way, without javascript (**without javascript**), to place the div on different sides of the button, depending of the available space in the viewport. Meaning,

If the button is at the top left corner, the div would show below the button and the left side of the div will be aligned with the left side of the button.

```
/----------------------------\
|                            |
| /--------\                 |
| | button |                 |
| \--------/                 |
| /-------------------\      |
| |                   |      |
| |     div           |      |
| |                   |      |
| |                   |      |
| \-------------------/      |
|                            |
\----------------------------/
```

If the button is at the bottom right corner, the div would show on top of the button, in such a way that the bottom of the div will be right on top of the button and the right side of the div will be aligned with the right side of the button:

```
/----------------------------\
|                            |
|                            |
|           /--------------\ |
|           |              | |
|           | div          | |
|           |              | |
|           |              | |
|           \--------------/ |
|                 /--------\ |
|                 | button | |
|                 \--------/ |
\----------------------------/
```

Etc...

Example:

```js
// Add your javascript here
$(function(){
  
  $('#btn').on("click", function() {
      if($('#content').is(":visible")) {
          $('#content').hide();
      }else{
          $('#content').show();
      }
      
  });
  
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

#webpage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 200px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

#btn {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 200px;
    border-color: 1px solid black;
    background: #999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="webpage">

        <div id="holder">
            <div id="btn">click me</div>
            <div id="content">content goes here</div>
        </div>
        <br >
        sdfasdgafdegsdefgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgvsdfgvsdfgvsdf        
        
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

EDIT:

So... It seems that some people aren't able to understand that this is a conceptual question. Let me draw a few more ASCII arts:

```
/----------------------------\
|                            |
| /--------\                 |
| | button |                 |
| \--------/                 |
| /-------------------\      |
| |                   |      |
| |     div           |      |
| |                   |      |
| |                   |      |
| \-------------------/      |
|                            |
\----------------------------/



/----------------------------\
|                            |
|                            |
|           /--------------\ |
|           |              | |
|           | div          | |
|           |              | |
|           |              | |
|           \--------------/ |
|                 /--------\ |
|                 | button | |
|                 \--------/ |
\----------------------------/





/----------------------------------\
|                                  |
|                                  |
|           /--------------\       |
|           |              |       |
|           | div          |       |
|           |              |       |
|           |              |       |
|           \--------------/       |
|                 /--------\       |
|                 | button |       |
|                 \--------/       |
\----------------------------------/




/----------------------------------\
|                                  |
|       /--------\                 |
|       | button |                 |
|       \--------/                 |
|       /-------------------\      |
|       |                   |      |
|       |     div           |      |
|       |                   |      |
|       |                   |      |
|       \-------------------/      |
|                                  |
\----------------------------------/



/----------------------------------\
|                                  |
|                  /--------\      |
|                  | button |      |
|                  \--------/      |
|       /-------------------\      |
|       |                   |      |
|       |     div           |      |
|       |                   |      |
|       |                   |      |
|       \-------------------/      |
|                                  |
\----------------------------------/




/----------------------------------\
|                                  |
|                                  |
|       /--------------\           |
|       |              |           |
|       | div          |           |
|       |              |           |
|       |              |           |
|       \--------------/           |
|       /--------\                 |
|       | button |                 |
|       \--------/                 |
\----------------------------------/


/----------------------------------\
|                                  |
|       /--------\                 |
|       | button |                 |
|       \--------/                 |
|       /-------------------\      |
|       |                   |      |
|       |     div           |      |
|       |                   |      |
|       |                   |      |
|       \-------------------/      |
|                                  |
\----------------------------------/
```

Comment: Try flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Not helpful at all.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using javascript, sorry.

Comment: Oh, @alexandernst, sorry, but I don't make the homework for you. If you need to change the normal flow without change the markup or without using javascript, your only solution is flexbox. If this doesn't solves your problem, you must to coding in javascript. Is that useful?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude No. Saying "use flexbox" is pretty much as useful as saying "Code it by coding it".

Comment: Oh yeah, and the link is hidden, huh? Remember that's a comment, not an answer

Comment: Obviously you didn't spent a minute in read the link I've been attached.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I spent a few hours trying to do it with all sort of flex and other css3 magic. You're not showing me something I haven't considered already.

Comment: Then use javascript, as I said in another comment. But in your question you said twice **without javascript**. So there's no another choice.

Comment: Are you saying that `flex-direction: column-reverse` doesn't solve your problem? Are you sure?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Are you sure you understand what I'm asking? How is the flex direction property going to change the entire position of the div in the viewport?

Comment: On a different note: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use JS? I mean you already use jQuery to show or hide the div, why not use it to position it too?

Comment: @mmgross I have been implementing menus and dropdowns and all they have this exact same problem. And I'm sick of having to reinvent the wheel every time I do something like that, so I thought I'd ask here and see if there is some way of doing that without javascript.

Comment: @alexandernst : *How is the flex direction property going to change the entire position of the div in the viewport?* Are you sure you used flexbox properly? Changing the position of an element and reacting to the dimensions of viewport is exactly what flexbox does, sir.

Comment: @zer00ne Then I suppose you won't have any problem with setting up a simple demo showing that?

Comment: @alexandernst I would if I understood the question better. Like this button...is it always on top left or is it sometimes in the opposite corner, or is those two positions represent two different states like opened and closed.

Comment: @zer00ne The question is very simple. Show a `div` aligned to left/right of a `point` (x, y) in the DOM, depending if there is enough space to show it on the left or on the right. If there is no enough space on the right side of the point, show the `div` on the left side of the point, else show it on the right. And same for top/bottom.

Comment: @alexandernst media queries and absolute position with percent or vw/vh measurements.

Comment: @zer00ne Perfect (if it works), please make a demo and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @alexandernst be happy to try, after work 12am UTC

Comment: @zer00ne Are you ready to share your solution?

Comment: @alexandernst Sorry, very busy, solution ready for review.

Answer (score 2):

## 1 OP:

> Is there a way, without javascript **(without javascript)**, to place the div on different sides of the button, depending of the available space in the viewport?

## 2 OP:

> The button can be placed anywhere in a page. And the viewport could be of any size. Media queries aren't helpful here, as the div should behave differently in the same-size viewport if the button is places at different locations.

...

> No... this is just a demo. Don't look at the positioning of the demo! Those are placeholder numbers. Think about the problem conceptually.

## 3 OP:

> Show a div aligned to left/right of a point (x, y) in the DOM, depending if there is enough space to show it on the left or on the right. If there is not enough space on the right side of the point, show the div on the left side of the point, else show it on the right. And same for top/bottom.

Going on the assumption that the last description, #3 OP, ***is the true and only question***, here is my answer:

OP did not prohibit the modification of HTML, so I removed `#holder` which proved to be useless and a hinderance. Useless in that the dropdown was not affected by it's absence. A hinderance in that the use of flexbox would be more complicated than needed. Those 2 factors and the fact that it was the only element without a style lead me to conclude that it was safe to remove. If OP required it, then perhaps that should be addressed in another question.

> *depending if there is enough space...*

...is a condition easily handled by JS and in a more broader way with CSS. [Media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) can handle changing styles once certain conditions are met such as viewport. I set a media query at 768px which is the generic breakpoint between mobile and desktop. OP was not specific as to what constitutes as *enough space*, so if there is an issue of space still, one must adjust the media query accordingly. (ex. 768px to 500px).

I have added an additional copy of the original that has no JS (no dropdown either), just to demonstrate that this solution depends on no JS.

## 4 OP:

> How is the flex direction property going to change the entire position of the div in the viewport?

Positioning is handled by [flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/). At the default stage--button over div (see figure 1 below), the key properties are as follows:

```
#webpage, #webpage2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    position: relative;
    align-items: flex-start;
    ...
}

#btn, #btn2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    ...
    order: 1;
    z-index: 10;
}
#content, #content2 {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    ...
    order: 2;
}
```

The second state--div over button (see figure 2 below), is triggered by the viewport width being less than or equal to 768px. When that condition is met, then the flexbox property [`order`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/) is changed as well as [`align-items`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/). The media query is as follows:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #webpage, #webpage2 {
        align-items: flex-end;
    }
    #content, #content2 {
        order: 1;
    }
    #btn, #btn2 {
        order: 2;
    }
```

Please review the Snippet and verify that media query and flexbox does indeed provide a means to change the positioning of elements upon a condition of *enough space* without JavaScript **(without JavaScript)**.

**Snippet**

```css
/*
#webpage2, #btn2, and #content2 are just an extension 
of this demo and is not a requirement of solution.
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>35845275</title>
  <style>
    body {
      position: relative;
    }
    #webpage,
    #webpage2 {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
      position: relative;
      align-items: flex-start;
      border: 1px solid green;
    }
    #webpage {
      top: 50px;
    }
    #webpage2 {
      top: 150px;
    }
    #btn,
    #btn2 {
      position: relative;
      top: 10px;
      left: 10px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      max-height: 20px;
      max-width: 120px;
      margin: 20px;
      order: 1;
      z-index: 10;
    }
    #content,
    #content2 {
      position: relative;
      display: none;
      height: 50vh;
      width: 200px;
      border-color: 1px solid black;
      background: #999;
      order: 2;
    }
    #content2 {
      display: block;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      #webpage,
      #webpage2 {
        align-items: flex-end;
      }
      #content,
      #content2 {
        order: 1;
      }
      #btn,
      #btn2 {
        order: 2;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="webpage">


    <button id="btn">click me</button>
    <section id="content">content goes here
      <p>
        <br>sdfasdgafdegsdefgsdfgsdfgsdfg sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgvsdfgv sdfgvsdf

      </p>
    </section>
  </div>



  <div id="webpage2">

    <button id="btn2">#BTN2</button>
    <section id="content2">#CONTENT2 goes here
      <p>
        <br>sdfasdgafdegsdefgsdfgsdfgsdfg sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgvsdfgv sdfgvsdf #CONTENT2
      </p>
    </section>

  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {

      $('#btn').on("click", function() {
        if ($('#content').is(":visible")) {
          $('#content').hide();
        } else {
          $('#content').show();
        }

      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Review of Snippet recommended in full page mode.

**Figure 1 - Initial Stage**

`align-items: flex-start` aligns elements to the left.

`order: 1` for `#btn` and `order: 2` for `#content`

```
/----------------------------\
|                            |
| /--------\                 |
| | button |                 |
| \--------/                 |
| /-------------------\      |
| |                   |      |
| |     div           |      |
| |                   |      |
| |                   |      |
| \-------------------/      |
|                            |
\----------------------------/
```

**Figure 2 - Secondary Stage**

`align-items: flex-end` aligns elements to the right.

`order: 2` for `#btn` and `order: 1` for `#content`

```
/----------------------------\
|                            |
|                            |
|           /--------------\ |
|           |              | |
|           | div          | |
|           |              | |
|           |              | |
|           \--------------/ |
|                 /--------\ |
|                 | button | |
|                 \--------/ |
\----------------------------/
```

**Note:** `position: absolute` (now changed to `position: relative`) was originally used make the dropdown overlap content. That can be accomplished by setting whatever needs to be overlapped by:
setting `position: relative` and `z-index: n` (n < 10) to the elements that you intend to overlap.

If OP intends to have buttons other than what was proscribed within this solution and the original question, it is a matter of reversing the key properties:

1. `align-items: flex-start or flex-end`
2. `order: 1 or 2` to the appropriate elements.

## Summary

@Marcos Pérez Gude suggestion to use flexbox is valid.

@Scott Marcus suggestion to use media queries is valid.

## Advice

When asking for help, do not dismiss what is offered, consider it, test it and give valid reasons why such advice would not help in your situation. Stay within the parameters of the question you ask. If you tell us to ignore something that you yourself has provided within the question, that makes your question invalid until you have edited it (and noted that it has been changed).

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3 Media Queries. This way you can write a style rule that positions the div where you need it for each width of the viewport. The general syntax of a Media Query is:

```
<style>
   /* Create default style rules here */

   @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
     /* place rules that apply to viewports up to 1280px here */
   }

   @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
     /* place rules that apply to viewports up to 960px here */
   }
</style>
```

There are many configurations for setting up media queries (min-width, max-width, width, min and max height, combinations, etc). This link may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: You haven't understood the question at all. Please re-read it.

Comment: @alexandernst Please explain what you think I'm not getting. I've re-read your question 3 times and it seems like this is a solution to the question you are asking.

Comment: Let's say the viewport width is 2000px. Always. Now, let's say I have placed the button at the bottom right corner of that 2000px wide viewport. How is any css media query going to help there?

Comment: Well, you haven't made it clear how it is determined that the button would be at the bottom-right when the viewport is 2000px wide, but in your example, a media query (as shown above) set to a max-wdith of 2000px would then contain a style rule to position the div absolutely and above the button. What's the problem?

Comment: The button can be placed anywhere in a page. And the viewport could be of any size. Media queries aren't helpful here, as the div should behave differently in the same-size viewport if the button is places at different locations.

Comment: Based on your example code, the content is 200px wide. And, since the content is inside of "holder", which does not have a width set for it, holder's width will be 100% the width of its parent element, which is "webpage". "webpage" is positioned 200px in from the left of the page, so content is roughly going to end 400px in from the left of the page. Since "btn" is going (according to the code you've shown) to be on a line above "content", we now have a minimum width of 400px to work with. With width wider than 400px, nothing would change.

Comment: If I am still not understanding your scenario, it's only because your code is indicating something different than your words are asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105569/discussion-between-alexandernst-and-scott-marcus).

Comment: No... this is just a demo. Don't look at the positioning of the demo! Those are placeholder numbers. Think about the problem conceptually.

Comment: When you post code on Stack Overflow, we don't think conceptually, we think about the code you've shown. Your question is poorly formed and is not conveying what you really are dealing with.